# how can I add a link with another link? example.com/page/subpage

Tags: hyperlink

I apologize in advance for my lack of coding vocabulary, but I was wondering if there's a way I can create a sublink that follows after a link?

*Reference:*

```
www.example.com/page/subpage
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Hi Nisse! For example, you visit the url: example.com. You then click on a link which directs you to example.com/project. Then, you click on a another link which directs you to example.com/project/information.

Comment: No, I don't think you can, or your question isn't clear enough. The closest I can come up with is making each part `example.com`, `page`, `subpage` individual links.

Comment: Hi! You're right about my lack of clarity, however after googling possible terminologies, I think the proper terminology is called "trailing slashes?" Any idea if that relates to what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

When a URL doesn't end with a file extension (such as .html), it generally references a default file within a file folder – usually "index.html."

**Examples:**

```
http://www.example.com              = http://www.example.com/index.html
http://www.example.com/page         = http://www.example.com/page/index.html
http://www.example.com/page/subpage = http://www.example.com/page/subpage/index.html
```

Some people recommend adding a trailing slash to a URL that ends with a folder name.  These are also equivalent:

```
http://www.example.com/page         = http://www.example.com/page/
http://www.example.com/page/subpage = http://www.example.com/page/subpage/
```

To create a working URL for `http://www.example.com/page/subpage`:

1. Create a `page` folder off your home directory.
2. Create a `subpage` folder off the `page` folder.
3. Create a file named `index.html` within the `subpage` folder.